# Permission Access to Employee Data(Record)

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, ssp

How can i get permission or access?

I'm trying to build search in `NETSUITE SSP` Application and I get the following error:

> `ERROR TITLE:` `"YOU_CANNOT_PERFORM_THIS_SEARCH_BECAUSE_YOU_DO_NOT_HAVE_PERMISSION_TO_ACCESS_EMPLOYEE_DATA"`

- I have tried: `nlapiloadrecord()`
- Then I tried saved search method to get employee record

**Search function**

```js
function getContact(sEmail) {
    var aFilter = new Array();
    aFilter.push(new nlobjSearchFilter('email', null, 'is', sEmail));
    var aResult = nlapiSearchRecord('employee', null, aFilter, null);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What role are you using while executing the above script?

If you only want to view(perform search) on employee record, you can contact your admin and ask them to give access on Employee record for the said role of type *View*.

You can check [this](https://system.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_N285436.html) out for further reading on **Roles** and how to create/edit/update one in NetSuite.

Comment: i have administrator account but don't know how to do employee record public for web services !! 
i had tried with all these mange role steps .but could not able to get rid of this situation !!